# Sum of reciprocals of the perfect powers

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, number-theory, riemann-zeta

- What is the sum of all of the numbers which can be written as the reciprocal of an integer that is also a power greater than one, excluding the powers of one ?.
- I'm asking about the sum of numbers which can be written as powers. $$
  \mbox{This sum would start off as}\quad
  \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{16} + \frac{1}{25} + \cdots
  $$

Note that I didn't count $1/16$ twice, as we are only adding numbers which can be written *in that form*.

-I can see how this alternative sum would have probably been easier to handle, since we can see that it equates to the sum $\zeta\left(s\right) - 1$ for all $s$ larger than one.
 - I know that the first sum must converge, because I have worked out that the sum of numbers which can be written in the form $1/\left(a^{b} - 1\right)$ converges to $1$, where
$a,b > 1$.

Is there any way of evaluating the first sum ?. Also, does the second sum converge as well and how can we evaluate it ?.

I have made a program $\left(~\texttt{python}~\right)$ which carries out partial sums for these sorts of series. I'll attach the source code if anyone wants it.

Comment: the first sum should have powers only once, my apologies if that's unclear

Comment: The partial sum for limit $n=10^9$ is ? s=0;for(j=1,10^9,if(ispower(j)>0,s=s+1.0/j));print(s)
0.8744322328535789186668554166
? (Calculated with PARI/GP)

Comment: yeah, i have tried it using the aforementioned program. Although, mine can only realistically do it to the order 10^5 terms...

Comment: @gebra Take a bit-set to sieve perfect powers first. A one GB array takes you to $2^{33}$, sieving doesn't take long. Sum "downwards", starting from the reciprocals of the largest powers to reduce floating point rounding effects.

Comment: the problem with sieving is you cant run it once and output values which will approach the limit, you'd have to choose the limit first

Comment: Allowing $1$ as a perfect power only adds $1$ to the sum

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The sum of the reciprocals of the perfect powers should be
$$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\sum_{j=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-\mu(k))}{j^k}=
\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\mu(k)\left(1-\zeta(k)\right)
\approx 0.874464$$
Where $\mu$ is the [Mobius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function).
See the OEIS sequence [A001597](http://oeis.org/A001597).

In order to verify the above formula, it suffices to show that in that double sum each perfect power is counted once. Now $n>1$ is a perfect power iff its prime factorization $p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_{r}^{a_r}$ satisfies $d:=\gcd(a_1,\dots, a_r)>1$.

In the above double sum, the denominator $j^k$ is equal to $n$ iff $k>1$ is a divisor of $d$ and $j=n^{1/k}$. Hence the fraction $1/n$ is counted the following number of times
$$\sum_{k\mid d,k>1}(-\mu(k))=0+\mu(1)=1$$
and we are done.

Comment: Why isn't it just the absolute value of $\mu(k)$?

Comment: @Turambar Consider the power $1/2^6$. In the sum with $-\mu(k)$ we will have $1/8^2+1/4^3-1/2^6=1/2^6$. With the the modulus we get  three copies of it: $1/8^2+1/4^3+1/2^6=3/2^6$.

Comment: Oh, I misread. I confused $j$ and $k$. In that case, I think it ought to be the absolute value of $\mu(j)$, as you don't want to consider the powers of $1/4$, $1/8$, etc. Or do these work out to be the same? I think this points to the necessity of showing the derivation.

Comment: This expression can be quickly and profitably simplified to $\sum_{k=2}^\infty \mu(k)\big(1-\zeta(k)\big)$; this makes it easy to calculate a huge number of decimal places of the value, since people have worked hard to find fast algorithms for calculating $\zeta(k)$, and the convergence of the infinite sum is awesome since the $k$th term is asymptotic to $2^{-k}$.

Comment: @Turambar I edited my answer with a proof of the formula.

Answer (score 6):

$$\begin{align} \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \left [\zeta(n)-1 \right ] &=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}  \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac1{k^n}\\ &= \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}  \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac1{k^n}\\ &= \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \left ( \frac{k}{k-1} - \frac{k+1}{k}\right ) \\ &= \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac1{k (k-1) }\\ &= 1\end{align}$$

NB

$$ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac1{k^n} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac1{k^n} - 1 - \frac1{k} = \frac{k}{k-1} - \frac{k+1}{k} $$

Comment: :/ This isn't necessarily a bad answer....?

Comment: Note that this answer does count $\frac 1 {16}$ twice, etc. This may explain the difference from Robert Z's answer.

Comment: Hey, this was meant to to be a quick and dirty answer to one of the questions posed above.  It was not meant to answer the other question, which apparently was answered by RobertZ.

Answer (score 4):

Your sum contains the sum of all reciprocals of non-unit natural number powers of primes, that is, every number of the form $\frac{1}{p^k}$ for prime $p$, and $k\in \{2,3,...\}=\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}$. Since each number of this form is uniquely determined by the choice of $p$ and $k$, we obtain

$\sum_{p}\sum_{i=2}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{p^i}=\sum_p\dfrac{1}{p(p-1)}$ where $p$ is every prime.

Since $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{p^i}=\dfrac{1}{p-1}$ (this follows from some basic number theory; an easy way to see it is to consider the repeating decimal, $0.111...$ in base $p$), yet we have removed the leading term, $\dfrac{1}{p}$, hence

$\sum_{p}\sum_{i=2}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{p^i}=\dfrac{1}{p-1}-\dfrac{1}{p}=\dfrac{p}{p(p-1)}-\dfrac{p-1}{p(p-1)}=\dfrac{p-(p-1)}{p(p-1)}=\dfrac{1}{p(p-1)}$

As for the case at hand, we are no longer concentrating on primes, but the prior counting result holds for non-prime numbers, $n$, the problem now is: how to avoid double counting numbers such as 4^2=4^2=16? Again the solution is to pick on primes, the prime here is $2$, thus we will count that as the $2^4$ and this tactic, in fact, handles all powers of $4$. But that doesn't solve the issue raised by numbers such as $36=2^2\cdot 3^2$. Here we have distinct primes that are part of the factorization, in this case, we can count this as $6^2$. We also have to deal with cases such as

$4^2\cdot 3^2=2^4\cdot 3^2=12^2=144$

For this, we consider it as $12^2$. By now the pattern is maybe emerging: We want take our sum of (non-unit) reciprocal powers over every number whose exponents of its prime factorization have gcd of 1. That is, We are interested in numbers:

$b=p_1^{k_1}\cdot p_2^{k_2}\cdot ...\cdot p_f^{k_f}$

for which $\gcd(k_1,...,k_f)=1$. The reason why this is the criterion we require is that we seek to eliminate recounts of numbers we already have, and any number which has the above $\gcd(k_1,...,k_f)=r\neq 1$, then we can take the $r$th root of that number, and obtain a number which *does* have $\gcd(k_1,...,k_f)=1$, hence we have a unique way of representing every number we care about as a power of a number in the above form with $\gcd(k_1,...,k_f)=1$.

Thus our sum is, in terms of the above notation:

$\sum_b\sum_{i=2}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{b^i}=\sum_b\dfrac{1}{b(b-1)}$.

I am not sure if there is a nice way of characterizing the relevant numbers $b$ or not, but provided a suitably nice characterization can be found this may prove useful.

Comment: 6^2 is a power, so yes. But still, i'd like to see where that solution comes from

Comment: $\sum_p 1/p$ is divergent

Comment: I made a few errors in coming up with that, working on a fix.

Comment: The inner sum should start at $i=2$, otherwise the sum clearly diverges as mrf notes.

Comment: Should be fixed now, also took the liberty of tying in my partial answer more directly to the OPs question.

Comment: Fixed an error with my characterization of the numbers, $b$, which are needed.

Comment: this is really interesting, how could we relate it to the mobius function as seen in one of the answers?

Comment: I honestly have no idea, as I know almost nothing about the möbius function.

Comment: @gebra Inclusion-exclusion principle. Say $n > 1$ is a perfect power. You can write it $n = b^k$ with maximal $k$. Then all ways to write $n$ as a (proper) power are $n = (b^{k/d})^d$ with $d$ dividing $k$ and $d > 1$. You want $\frac{1}{n}$ to be counted only once. Noting $\sum\limits_{d\mid k} \mu(d) = 0$ since $k > 1$, it follows that $$1 = \mu(1) = \sum_{\substack{d \mid k \\ d > 1}} (-\mu(d)).$$